# how to get count of single column while getting data from different tables based on Id

Tags: sql, join, count, subquery

I wrote query for getting data from different  tables, Totally I have to get 3 columns of data from 3 tables based on Id, And one of those columns is I have to get count of rows of the table

```
SELECT vm.Vendor_Name, vc.Contact_Name, COUNT(po.Purchase_order)
FROM vendor_master vm JOIN
     purchase_order po
     ON po.vendor_id = vm.vendor_id JOIN
     vendor_contacts vc
     ON vc.Vend_id = vm.vendor_id JOIN
     payment_master pm
     ON pm.Vendor_id = vm.vendor_id
WHERE vm.vendor_id = 1;
```

I wrote Above query for that but its giving some error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you will use an aggregate function with some column selection you need group by those columns

```
SELECT vm.Vendor_Name, vc.Contact_Name, COUNT(po.Purchase_order)
FROM vendor_master vm JOIN
     purchase_order po
     ON po.vendor_id = vm.vendor_id JOIN
     vendor_contacts vc
     ON vc.Vend_id = vm.vendor_id JOIN
     payment_master pm
     ON pm.Vendor_id = vm.vendor_id
WHERE vm.vendor_id = 1
group by vm.Vendor_Name, vc.Contact_Name
```

so you are missing group by in your query

Answer (score 0):

You seem to need a `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT vm.Vendor_Name, vc.Contact_Name, COUNT(po.Purchase_order)
FROM vendor_master vm JOIN
     purchase_order po
     ON po.vendor_id = vm.vendor_id JOIN
     vendor_contacts vc
     ON vc.Vend_id = vm.vendor_id JOIN
     payment_master pm
     ON pm.Vendor_id = vm.vendor_id
WHERE vm.vendor_id = 1
GROUP BY vm.Vendor_Name, vc.Contact_Name;
```